# Extracting values from a Javascript Object

Tags: javascript

I am trying o get data from SWAPI to integrate with another platform using javascript. I have some saved some links inside a variable while getting data.

```js
a = {
  items: [
    { item: "https://swapi.dev/api/people/5/" },
    { item: "https://swapi.dev/api/people/68/" },
    { item: "https://swapi.dev/api/people/81/" },
  ],
};
```

From this code how do I extract the links only and save in a variable? I only need links. I tried `object.values`, `object.keys()` but couldn't find a way. The platform I am using doesn't support `fetch()` or `$.each`.

I am not quite sure how to get it done using `for` loop. Any assistance will be highly appreciated!

Comment: `a.items.map(({ item }) => item)` will produce an array of just the URLs

Answer (score 0):

You can use a simple `forEach` for this task like:

```js
const a = {
  "items": [{
      "item": "https://swapi.dev/api/people/5/"
    }, {
      "item": "https://swapi.dev/api/people/68/"
    },
    {
      "item": "https://swapi.dev/api/people/81/"
    }
  ]
};

a.items.forEach(el =>{
  console.log(el.item);
});
```

Reference:

- [Array.prototype.forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)

Answer (score 0):

There are many different ways to achieve this, a few already suggested.

Using a `for` loop:

```js
// Create an empty array to store the values
const linksArray = [];

// Loop the object items array to get its values
for (let i = 0; i < a.items.length; i++) {
  // Store the values in the empty array
  linksArray.push(a.items[i].item);
}

// See the results
console.log(linksArray)
```